# istringstream put string back on input and read again

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stringstream

So i read out lines out of a file and then read out the lines via stringstream.

I found the Issue that because of the format of the line rarely 2 seperate parts are written together and get read together as one string. I tryed to fix that situation by putting the wrong read value back on the stream and read again but it looks like istringstream doesnt care i put the chars back. they simply dont get read out again.

Here the Problem broken down. S1 is a good string. S2 adresses the Issue with the wrong read in the comments:

In short. Is it possible to put a string back on istringstream and read it with the next operation??

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::string device_id;              //126, I_VS_MainVoltageAvailabl
    std::string ea_type;                //E
    std::string address;                //0.1
    std::string data_type;              //BOOL
    std::vector<std::string> comment;   //VS - Steuerspannung vorhanden / Main voltage available"

    std::string s1 = "126,I_Btn_function_stop     E       1.2 BOOL      Taster Stopp Funktion / Button Stop Function";
    std::string s2 = "126,I_VS_MainVoltageAvailablE       0.1 BOOL      VS - Steuerspannung vorhanden / Main voltage available";

    std::istringstream ist{ s2 };
    ist >> device_id;                   // Read 126, I_VS_MainVoltageAvailablE    the E should be read in ea_type
    ist >> ea_type;                     // 0.1

    //my idea
    if (!ea_type.empty() && isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ea_type[0]))) {  //first is a digit so already next was read

        for (const auto& x : ea_type)       //Try to put 0.1 in the stream
            ist.putback(x);

        ea_type = device_id[device_id.size() - 1];      // = "E"
        device_id.pop_back();                           // = "126, I_VS_MainVoltageAvailabl"
    }
    ist >> address;                                     // Expected "0.1" instead  "BOOL" why 0.1 was putback on the stream???
    ist >> data_type;

    for (std::string in; ist >> in;)
        comment.push_back(in);
}
```

Comment: `std::basic_istream` derivatives aren't the right tool for this. Use a normal `std::string` or vector to get and put back as needed. However, you may be able to manipulate the underlying `std::stream_buf`, but it's a complicated and quite limited walkaround

Comment: @WhiZTiM why are you saying so? It is perfectly cool to use `stringstream`'s putback, just not `istringstream`, which is input-only.

Comment: @SergeyA, yeah my comment was based on the OP's context of using `std::istringstream`. `std::stringstream` behaves as both input and output stream, so, that would be fine;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, people are ignoring return codes. `putback` has a return code for a reason, and when it is false, it means `putback` failed.

In particular, `std::istringstream` is *input* string stream, and as such, is input-only stream. Because of that, you can't use `putback` on it, it will always fail.

However, you can use `std::stringstream` instead, and with that `putback` will behave the way you want it to.

Comment: thats it i switched to stringstream and it works. why you can use `istringstream::putback` when it never works with `istringstream`?

Comment: _As usual, people are ignoring return codes._ So cynical.  All we can say for sure is that in this case Sandro4912 is ignoring return codes.

Comment: @Sandro4912, because `putback` is a function inherited from base class. The inheritance-based design of C++ streams has several drawbacks, and this is one of them.

Comment: `putback` seems to be working fine for me in a more general case: https://ideone.com/G1ZYp5 . Definitely check the return code though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your logic is malformed. What you actually have is a fixed field format which is not amenable to the istream extraction operators.

You would do better to read a whole line of input, then extract the "fields" by their column offsets.

Or, read one byte at a time, appending to the string variable you want to extract, until you have read enough bytes to fill it. That is, read 29 bytes into device_id, then however many (1? 8?) bytes into ea_type, etc.

I want to question your comments, though. The istream string extractor `operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)` will pull one *space delimited* token off the input stream. In other words, your first extraction pulls off `"126,"`. So the rest of the logic is completely wrong.